# Show The End of Scrollbar with 100% Height

Tags: css

I have a position: absolute div, with top: 114px and overflow: auto. I added height: 100% to the div, the scroll shows but the bottom of the div is covered, including the end of the scroll. How to make the bottom of the scroll shows?

I tried to change the div to position: relative; overflow: auto; top: 0px; height: 100%; but no scrollbar shown.

Anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please post the associated HTML, preferably as a fiddle.

Comment: can u try moving the `overflow:auto` to the element outside this div.

Comment: @Justinas top: 0 still the end of scrollbar is hided. and I need the top to be 114px

Comment: Set `top: 114px; height: calc(100% - 114px);`, and remove paddings + margins from parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what behavior you want to achieve, but I guess what you needed is just adding "bottom: 0px;" to your absolutely positioned div.

The whole solution:

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden; /* Page doesn't scroll... */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* ...but the content does. */
    overflow-x: auto;
    top: 114px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffdf00;    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tzyzmxjv/1/